# VBA code to remember file chosen before

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the Bos and Dos to choose the same file that was prompted before at Bos.

When I use the ADailyReport macro, it prompts the file again.

```
Sub Bos()
    Dim filename__path As Variant
    filename__path = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                     FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLS", _
                     Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If filename__path = False Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=filename__path
    Sheets("HSE").Select
    Range("L23:M23").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Follow-up .xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("BE803").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=270
    Range("B431").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Sub Dos()
    Dim filename__path As Variant
    filename__path = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                     FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLS", _
                     Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If filename__path = False Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=filename__path
    Sheets("HSE").Select
    Range("L24:M24").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Follow-up .xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("BE803").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=270
    Range("D431").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Sub ADailyReport()
 Application.Run "'C:\Users\Follow-up .xlsm'!Bos"
 Application.Run "'C:\Users\Follow-up .xlsm'!Dos"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable reference for Dos and just make a call on it in Bos or vice versa.
Something like:

```
Sub Bos()
    '~~> rest of your code here for Bos
    '~~> then call Dos
    Dos filename_path
End Sub
```

Dos on the other hand should be set up like:

```
Sub Dos(mypath As Variant)
    If mypath = False Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open mypath
    '~~> rest of the code here
End Sub
```

This way, Dos is automatically ran when Bos is executed.

Another way is you can use a *Global/Public Variable*.
So Bos and Dos is still run independently but if one or the other is already executed, it will not prompt for the file.

```
Option Explicit
Public filename_path As Variant

Sub Bos()
   If IsEmpty(filename_path) Then
       filename_path = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                 FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLS", _
                 Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
   End If

   If filename_path = False Then Exit Sub
   '~~> Rest of your code here
End Sub
```

Set up Dos the same way as above. HTH.
It is worth noting though that *Global/Public* variable persist as long as the file is not closed or until no errors were encountered to make the macro break. So for you to load a different file (after loading the first file), you will need to save and close the file first. Or you can add additional query if the user wants to load a different file aside from what's stored in memory.